# Don't show suggested edits that I can't approve

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

I'm seeing suggested edits to tag wikis on Stack Overflow which I do not have the ability to approve. Could you just not show me those?

Comment: I don't think I can approve tag wiki's any more today, but I keep seeing them, it's annoying.

Comment: Could yo post a screen shot? or link? I'm not sure what you mean, sorry!

Comment: @trufa it's a new ability for 10k+ users. users who don't have enough rep to make an edit can make suggested edits, which can then be approved or declined by a 10k+ user. but it also shows edits to tag wikis, which not all 10k+ users can edit. the url is http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits, but you probably can't get to it

Comment: I was just curious :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I made a couple of changes that may help alleviate this problem.</strike>

1. We suppress the queue notification if there are fewer than 5 pending items in the queue
2. 20k users can approve all tag wiki changes

I agree it makes sense hiding the items, however it is a reasonably expensive calculation that I do not want to do on all page loads. Even doing it on `/review/edit-suggestions' is a little expensive.

The whole suggested edit system has made me rethink tag wiki requirements, we now allow all people with access to the pending edit suggestion queue the rights to approve tag wiki edits. 20k users can edit all tag wikis with no restrictions.

In retrospect the complex requirements for tag wikis made no sense, they are too hard to explain, pure reputation is much simpler.

Comment: but aren't you doing it on the reviews page? I think there was no approve/deny button for me when I looked at a tag wiki suggestion, which would mean you're determining at that point whether or not to show those buttons

Comment: It's hard for me to believe that the calculation is (marginally) all that expensive.  If you've already checked to see whether the user has /some/ approval permission (10K+), how much more processing would be needed to check for /full/ approval permission (20k+)?

Comment: I'm not sure why doing it on /review is difficult either. There's already no buttons on the ones I can't approve; I was planning to just write a script that looks for posts without an approve button and hides them

Comment: In a case like is occurring right now, there are 10 wiki edits in the queue (and guessing from recent activity, it will keep growing) and so we're stuck with an annoying notification badge until a 20k comes along. I actually dislike the 5-pending limit and wish it would show up for 1+

Comment: @Carl: I think it may be the other ways to have approval rights that are expensive.  For tag wikis, I should think it's 20k rep OR 10k rep and N upvotes in the tag OR 10k rep and being one of the top users in that tag.  The latter options could be more intensive calculations.

Comment: Don't show me tag-wiki edits I can't approve. It's hugely annoying. Also, approves/rejects by people who *have* the needed requirements for a specific wiki should have more weight IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there are (at least) two kinds of suggested edits: tag wiki and question edits and the rep threshold for those also seems to be different: I had the notice for suggested edit by I wondered how I could edit a wiki tag: there was nothing visible.
When I went back to the [SO suggested edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), I had the ability to approve/deny a question retag.