# suggested edit feature getting a deluge of tag wiki edit requests

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-wiki, suggested-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

There seems to be a glut of low-quality tag wiki edit suggestions coming from low rep users.  So many from the same user, that I'm not allowed to vote on them all.  Right now [Mark Hurd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256431/mark-hurd) is a big offender.

Can this be changed so that suggesting an edit to a tag wiki requires some rep in that tag, albeit less than is needed for a direct edit?

Maybe 15% as many upvotes should be required to suggest an edit as for a self-approved edit.

Comment: @Pekka: Maybe a rate limit would be better.  It would encourage users to spend some time and actually read the wikipedia articles they're excerpting and/or some of the questions in the tag, and understand the tag they're writing a wiki for.  Because really, suggesting a tag wiki for "inheritance" that doesn't mention polymorphism (and excludes the classic VB implementation of inheritance) isn't all that useful.

Comment: Considering how many tags have no wiki at all I don't like additional barriers to tag-wikis. Giving a one sentence definition doesn't require much knowledge of the topic.

Comment: BTW My "glut" has finished. I thought a starting simple description with a link to a Wikipedia article was a good first step -- definitely better than nothing. The suggested editing feature is probably missing the feedback that Wikipedia provides by editing the user's talk page.

Comment: @Mark: We appreciate you taking the time to write tag wikis, but please take the time to read 5-6 questions from the tag, and more than a cursory look at the Wikipedia article.  But you were submitted 3 or more new tag wikis in less than 60 seconds.  At 20 seconds per tag, the best case is that someone is going to have to come in and rewrite it, which is no change from how you found it, and quite possibly you'll summarize completely the wrong topic or on a subset of the topic as discussed on SO, which may lead to mistagging of future questions.

Comment: @Mark: Also, the wikipedia content license requires you to attribute any content you lift from the site.  A link is part of that, but my understanding is that you also need to say that the content came from there, a link by itself is not enough.

Comment: @Ben I may have submitted a couple of edits at the same time, but I did review the first page of questions for all tags I submitted tag wikis. When I directly quoted the Wikipedia article I mentioned it. When I used my own words I didn't.

Comment: BTW I assume I only get rep for accepted edits. In that case I produced 26 accepted tag wikis on SO and 19 on Meta. Note also that the date in the activity is when they're accepted, not when I suggested the edit.

Comment: @Ben I am actually quite offended your are calling the edits @Mark submitted "glut", he has a **very** high hit rate, more than 80% of his edits get approved by no less than to 10k users. He is using the system as designed and helping out. This only serves to discourage him.

Comment: Please don't describe someone who is _giving_ a lot of their `free time` as an 'offender'. It _takes time_ to propose such edits, and yes it takes time to critique them. How is the system _not_ working?

Comment: @Tim: If that were so, there'd be no problem.  But we're talking 3+ new tag wikis in under a minute.  That's broken.  I think we want the system to encourage a user who has 20 minutes to donate to do a good job on 3-4 tags instead of a thoughtless job on 50 tags.  @waffles: There are 10k users who approve *everything* that comes across the suggested edits page regardless of whether the approver understands the material and possibly without reading it.  Are there statistics for "time between viewing the suggested edit page and hitting approve"?

Comment: @Ben ... these same users can just edit the site willy-nilly and wreak havoc, I agree I have seen some users that approve stuff too fast. However, writing tag wiki excerpts is not something that takes 20 minutes, the body sure ... but the short excerpt which is **critical** only takes a minute or so

Comment: @Ben - We're talking about wikis that did not _exist_ that someone took some time to create. I'm sorry, but a _wrong_ wiki invites the creation of something correct much more than the absence of one, as illustrated by this question. Again, I ask you, how is the system _not_ working? :)

Comment: @waffles: If you do the math on my comment, I was saying about 5-6 minutes per tag, for both the excerpt and a first draft of the wiki body.  IMO 20-30 *second* is much too short.  @Tim: I apparently have a different idea of "took some time to create".  I don't think typing the term into wikipedia and cutting and pasting the first sentence qualifies as "taking time" or "creation".

Comment: @Ben can you look through this list and tell me what percentage you think are bad? http://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-changed-wikis?page=1

Comment: @waffles: The `infragistics` one seems poor, it suggests that they are a services/contract development company ("specializing in") when actually they sell widget libraries.  The `JavaScript` excerpt probably ought to say something about being used most commonly with web browsers.  `SMS` is a straight-up cut+paste from wikipedia and the excerpt ends mid-word.    The summary of `STS` is relevant to barely half the tagged questions, the other half mean "Security Token Service".  The `events` wiki is obviously cut+pasted without giving credit to the source.  More than 25% are low quality wikis.

Comment: "More than 25% are low quality wikis." - ok so you choose, would you prefer 25% low quality wikis (in your words), or 10x less wikis on SO. Keep in mind, anyone, including yourself could help clean up the problem wikis.

Comment: @waffles: What I didn't mention is that only about 15% were *reasonably* good wikis.  The other half I don't have the expertise to judge (most of the wikis being added are pretty obscure).  If I can spot 2 low quality ones for every good one, yeah I think there's a problem.  I would further venture to guess that 99% of wiki summaries written in under 60 seconds are low quality, some rate limiting wouldn't hurt.  If you think that badly written wikis get more attention from the domain experts than empty ones, why not auto-fill empty wikis with "`tag` is crap.  Use `random-other-tag` instead."?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ooh, I like that idea for attracting edits!

Answer (score 8):

We already rate limit suggested edits, if you submit a large number of poor suggested edits you will be automatically banned from suggesting edits for a period of time.

The correct thing to do here is reject the poor suggested edits, then we can automatically ban as required. If noise persists we can escalate the ban.

---

Also, I am actually quite offended your are calling the edits Mark submitted "glut", he has a very high hit rate, more than 80% of his edits get approved by no less than two 10k users. He is using the system as designed and helping out. This only serves to discourage him.

---

I am not re-introducing the complexity around suggesting tag-wikis, people never *got it*, it just caused confusion and too many tag wikis were left blank. We are seeing a [maintainable and auditable](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/recently-changed-wikis?page=1) list of wiki changes. Looking through what happened today all looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think encouraging people not to help is the right answer. The right answer is:
[Don't show suggested edits that I can't approve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77774/dont-show-suggested-edits-that-i-cant-approve)

And yes, I too am annoyed by the glut of Mark Hurd's edits; but only because I can't *do* anything with them, not because I think he shouldn't be trying to add information where none exists.

Comment: Well, the existence of a suggested edit seems to be preventing me from accessing the direct edit function and putting in a more comprehensive description.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Wait, you're a 20k+...can't you go through and approve/reject them all, per @waffles's answer?

Comment: There's a limit of three approve/reject to a specific user per day. That's why @BenVoigt can't approve/reject them all. See Pekka's [request to increase the limit about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78232/).

Comment: @Phrogz: Well, I found a workaround: By visiting the tag wiki edit history first, I can reach the edit page.

Comment: @Phrogz ... the like you posted is status-completed

Comment: @waffles w00t, thanks :) Does this also cover not showing flagged comments that I can't do anything about?

Comment: @Phrogz ... this is unrelated to flagging