# Can the per-person approve limit be raised for higher-rep users?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

As pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/how-many-edits-can-i-approve-in-a-day), one can approve a maximum of 3 edits from a specific user per day to prevent gaming.

Could this be relaxed a bit, maybe on a sliding scale, with one additional vote for each 5k or 10k of reputation?

There is a user making a series of good edits to tag wikis and I'd like to approve them, but I can't. The edits have been waiting in the queue for fifteen minutes now. This is likely to be a bit of a hindrance in the future whenever <2k users go on a (useful) editing spree.

On the other hand, it's sunday so traffic is low. Otherwise, the edits would probably have been approved away within thirty seconds. So maybe this is not a real problem most of the time.

Maybe relax it only for tag wikis, on the basis that they need extra love, and frivolous edits and gaming are easier to uncover there?

Comment: I think that a person with sufficient reputation to make the same edit directly should be able to just approve the edit, but that's just mho. I guess the purpose is to gain additional review, especially in the case of specialized tag wikis. Still, I don't approve edits to tag wikis where I can't adequately judge the value of the edit.

Comment: Are you referring to Mark Hurd's edit queue?  I find his suggestions to be quite low-quality and [added a feature request to require at least a few upvotes before making tag wiki suggestions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78229/suggested-edit-feature-getting-a-deluge-of-tag-wiki-edit-requests).

Comment: @Tim I think it's specifically the gaming aspect that this is designed to prevent (the possibility to create 2k users by making thousands of frivolous edits and approving them, in theory even in an automated fashion).

Comment: @Ben heh, two different requests for the same queue :) I tend to like the edits (which seem to be Wikipedia quotes mainly) on the basis that it's a start for each tag. They're not expert material but it's better than nothing. But I see your point, too... However that was not the only user I was referring to, there were two others who seemed to have some time on their hands today but whose contributions have gone through since.

Comment: I just went through the list and accepted 2, but I couldn't decide whether or not to accept or reject the others so I left them.

Comment: @Pekka, is this still a problem, in light of the approve wiki rule changes?

Comment: @waffles I didn't actively watch, but the queue seemed to have emptied so quickly today that I never had the chance to actually check anything :) I guess that means it's working. If I notice anything to the contrary in the next few days, I'll follow up here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag wiki approval requirements will be heavily relaxed tomorrow. I am pretty sure the current system will do fine as soon as that is in place cause all the eyes which are on on the queue will be able to approve all the wikis.

If we find out that this is still a problem in a day or 2 after it is deployed we can revisit.

Comment: note we can also increase the notification panic to 10 from 5, so you do not see the queue notification unless there are 10 or more edits waiting

Comment: Increasing the queue length directly increases the time each of those edits is in the "waiting for approval" state, because people only look at the queue once the notification shows up. I don't really think increasing the time each edit waits for approval is a good thing. In the beginning all edits were approved in seconds, now it probably takes 15 minutes on average (since nobody is notified of pending edits earlier). If you require 10 items before notification that time would probably double again.