# Need to Change Edit Approval Limits for Tag Wiki Editors

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

The user [Jakub Konecki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/449906/jakub-konecki) has been doing a lot of tag wiki edits. I'd like to approve them, but I'm out of votes - I can't vote on him anymore.

That would be fine, except that, for the past ten minutes or so, six of his edits have been sitting there in the queue - I bet others who might approve his edits are in the same position as I am.

I think this should be adjusted somehow.

Comment: [A very similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78232/can-the-per-person-approve-limit-be-raised-for-higher-rep-users), though geared specifically towards some sort of reputation scale

Comment: I am in the same boat as you, but there may be an issue with some of his suggestions. See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81047/copy-and-pasting-wikipedia-articles-into-tag-wikis

Comment: I've been unable to approve his edits since early today.

Answer (score 3):

I just upped it from 3 to 5.

Hopefully this alleviates the issue a bit. If we still notice a pattern of users being blocked we can look at adjusting further.