# Should links to Wikipedia be removed or disallowed on tag wiki pages?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, wikipedia

I was just browsing through the review tab, and I saw a link to Wikipedia at the bottom of a tag information/about page. After looking around, I have seen quite a few of these. (I was going to post on [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/), but this is probably Stack Exchange-wide).

Shouldn't tag wiki pages have all the necessary information contained in them so that a user would have no need to leave the site? Or even possibly a syndication of Wikipedia data (a la Facebook info pages)?

To me, it just seems a little strange.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we do anything against tag wikis copy-pasted from Wikipedia?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102314/can-we-do-anything-against-tag-wikis-copy-pasted-from-wikipedia)

Answer (score 13):

The link should not be provided in order to direct the user away, it should be provided [in order to meet Wikipedia's attribution requirements](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-do-we-feel-about-raiding-wikipedia-for-device-descriptions/466#466).  Although, there are some topics with gigantic, in-depth Wikipedia articles; I see no need to provide that much information here.  Tag wikis are not a primary repository of knowledge.

Wikipedia has a lot of good information, so I see no reason not to take advantage of it.  Ideally our tag wikis will be customized to our sites and go beyond a wiki excerpt, but it's a great starting point.

Note that, as Jeff says on the question I linked above, basic concepts need not be defined in tag wikis.  Linking to Wikipedia for the sake of it, or in order to prevent a wiki from being blank, is not useful.