# Edits that add nothing but random formatting

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)
>   [If it is in italic, it must be pretty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/if-it-is-in-italic-it-must-be-pretty)

Edits like this one: [Com Add-In not showing up in Com Add-Ins window in Excel 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848968/com-add-in-not-showing-up-in-com-add-ins-window-in-excel-2003)   ([revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11848968/revisions))

The edit adds nothing to the question, but just adds formatting tags around what appear to be completely arbitrary places.

Should we be encouraging this type of edit? While I understand that some formatting helps (line breaks, paragraph breaks, indenting code) the reason of `Good question!!Just made it little flashy!!Thanks!!` adds nothing.

Comment: Just roll it back. I did that for you.

Comment: There have been lots of terrible edits of that sort. We're really not sure `why` people `inline code` random `words`

Comment: ok.. but this user has gained 24 rep today from just doing these flashy edits.... someone is approving them :)

Comment: New suspension reason: inline code applied to random words

Comment: @BenBrocka Make that a feature request pretty please? ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848905/select-last-12-rows-oracle#comment15759542_11848905

Comment: I'm more disappointed in the folks who approved nine bad edits (and those who cast approval votes on the twelve rejected edits). We will always have bad editors, and we're supposed to have a system to protect the site from them.

Comment: @Bart: *"You can explicitly notify one (1) other commenter, editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question"* -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks. Removed my comment because I just found that exact link. I was unaware of that.

Comment: Related: [Reject an already-approved suggested edit when rolling it back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back) and [What can we do to stop bad edits getting accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted)

Comment: `I` definitely `agree that` it adds `nothing` to the `question`.

Comment: oh shoot! I rejected many of this guy's edits, I was furiously clicking "Approve" on the previous one and approved this by mistake. I wish there was a way to change the reviews' verdict. @Arjan, thanks for notifying me.

Comment: Related: [Is there an actual "accept ALL the suggested edits" problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140017)

Comment: There was a user yesterday gunning for the Archaeologist badge, and proceeded to edit over 100 questions more than 2 years old by adding `<!-- language: lang-js -->` to all of the already-formatted code tags. They had enough reputation so that none of the edits needed approval.

Comment: I see exactly _one_ suggestion that was actually helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/343558 Nearly all of them have the description "Good question!!Just made it little flashy!!Thanks!!" Only seven of them were rejected. Urgh.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That is a terrible edit, and it should have been rejected. Code markup is for - believe it or not - code, not for random highlighting of text fragments.

Comment: and what if the user has enough reputation to edit without approval, but deems their minor edits necessary anyways? Just keep rolling them back?

Comment: Rollback, `@msg` them, if they persist, take it to the mods, they have more authority educating users on correct editing than you or I.

Answer (score 12):

In borderline cases, reject as invalid. In the severe cases where they just spray code formatting randomly, reject as vandalism. Repeat until their will is broken.

Remember that people who have too many suggestions rejected are banned from suggesting further edits for a week--Hope is not lost! (Although ideally, suggestion bans would get longer each time to get one.)

Now we just need to figure out [what to do about people who approve bad edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted).

Comment: +1: I wish I could mark 2 answers as correct