# Edits that use grave accent tags just for highlighting

Tags: discussion, edits, abuse

Moments ago, in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393509/overlaying-a-rectangle-over-map-in-iphone (specifically this [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14393509/2)), I found some strange formatting with 
 grave accent(`) tags used not for the code but just for highlighting. Since I don't have the privilege to revert edits, I simply re-suggest-edit it.

Then I took a loot into the editor's profile and found these:

1. [MPMoviePlayer shows a solid black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379122/mpmovieplayer-shows-a-solid-black-screen) ([link to revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14379122/revisions))
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379568/cocoa-app-webview-download-from-url ([link to revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14379568/revisions))
3. [Multiplying and dividing CGFloat and loss of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379541/multiplying-and-dividing-cgfloat-and-loss-of-precision) ([link to revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14379541/revisions))

I searched meta and found this: [Edits that add nothing but random formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142558/edits-that-add-nothing-but-random-formatting), so if I understand correctly, those edits listed above are not appropriate.

If that's true, since I cannot revert revised edits, is it appropriate I edit all of them back?

Comment: Infuriatingly, after your rollback, someone *else* came through and added `random` code `formatting` *back* to the quesstion!  How the hell is this crap getting approved?

Comment: I've rolled back the listed edits and flagged one for moderator attention, in case this question is missed.  That style of editing is entirely inappropriate and the user needs a whack upside the head.

Comment: +1 for the whack but in my opinion it should be extended to edit approvers. Did they even read the edit before approving ?

Comment: @dystroy: This has been discussed many times here, [here is a good starting point to find these discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back

Answer (score 1):

The grave accent used to format code in the post, sometimes editor used it to highlight the text instead of bold formatting or italics. You can edit all them back unless you have enough reputation your edits should be approved by the reviewers.