# Users blindly approving suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an actual “accept ALL the suggested edits” problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140017/is-there-an-actual-accept-all-the-suggested-edits-problem)
>   [The current review system encourages fake reviews; some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

Recently I've noticed quite a few users blindly approving all suggested edits and that's getting somewhat annoying.

For example user [MaVRoSCy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387157/mavroscy) "has approved 267 edit suggestions and rejected 0 edit suggestions".

Examples:

- [a comment/reply as an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/823123)
- [a minor/misleading edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/812031)
- [a minor and incorrect edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/835020) (introduces formatting to a code block)
- [an unnecessary edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/835024) (although not that clear)

This doesn't seem right. At the very least there should be a similar notice that appears when you haven't voted on questions for a while that says *"You haven't rejected a suggested edit in a while, reviewing doesn't consist of only approving suggested edits?"*

A better solution would be to track someones review history and if he approves too many edits that ultimately are rejected, then the system can take more affirmative action.

Such behavior doesn't help the site's quality imho.