# Should we instruct how to create and review tag wikis better?

Tags: discussion, review, tag-wiki

I've just ran across these two edit suggestions:

- A [wiki excerpt suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5084642) which is a complete copypasta with apparently no attribution, and of course, not condensed enough to be helpful as an excerpt. This one was approved.
- a [wiki suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5084644) which is, put simply, completely useless to the site and the community. Even then, two users voted to approve this.

Is there any way to better instruct tag editors and reviewers, as well as aiding them in the process?

---

As far as I can see, the editor possibly thought it was okay to throw in the copypasta into the excerpt and attribute it in the wiki body. I'm not sure if that is okay, but I'm sure copypastas are hardly ever suitable for a wiki excerpt. Should also note that as the wiki body has been rejected, there is no attribution whatsoever right now.

### Improve the tag wiki editing experience

Right now, the tag wiki editing page displays [this side text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN5XY.png), but it doesn't feel very attractive, it also does not look as important as it actually is, being pushed aside from the page like that. The editor, in this case, completely ignored the side text.

Another issue is that the side text does not mention proper attribution, which is a quite frequent rejection reason. In fact, detecting plagiarism is an arduous task, wouldn't it be possible for the SE engine to detect and reject when a tag wiki edit consists of 100% copypasta without attribution, giving the editor a helpful message?

Still on the side text topic, the side text contains a link to [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) as a reference for writing good tag wikis. It is a good reference, indeed. However, a blog post seems way too long-winded for editors that simply want to write a tag wiki. A Help Center page would be more objective, easier to find and useful, in my opinion.

It might also be worth nothing that the current minimum length for a tag wiki body is 30 characters, I believe this could be bumped up a little.

### Improve the tag wiki reviewing experience

Currently, reviewers are simply given the privilege to review tag wiki and excerpt edits after attaining 5,000 reputation, in contrast to the 20,000 reputation required to edit a tag wiki without going through peer review. I'm not sure whether raising the required reputation would be helpful, but it is one thing to consider.

In my opinion, the main issue with reviewers is that they are capable of reviewing tag wikis without ever having edited one themselves, that is, without even going through the (relatively poor) side text in the tag wiki editing screen.

I believe adding a "Help" button in the tag wiki review screen would be tremendously useful for new tag wiki reviewers. The Help button could display a popup/sidebar with the aforementioned tag wiki's side text tips, or simply link to a Help Center page version of the [redesigned tags page blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

---

These are just some ideas and my personal views, feel free to comment and answer with your own Tag Wiki creating/editing/reviewing improvement suggestions and opinions.

I don't expect all of these suggestions to be implemented, rather I'd like to discuss their viability and get more suggestions from the community before making a proper feature request.

Comment: Oh gosh, that tag wiki. O.O The two who chose to approve that will be taking a break from review for a few days...

Comment: @animuson thanks for the quick action. I've posted this on MSE as I believe all SE sites can benefit from these improvement suggestions, but feel free to move this topic to MSO if you find it more suitable.

Comment: Raising the reputation requirements wouldn't help. I've had to explain to moderators that systematic Wikipedia copypasta wasn't useful. Related: [Can we do anything against tag wikis copy-pasted from Wikipedia?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102314/can-we-do-anything-against-tag-wikis-copy-pasted-from-wikipedia), [Feature request: large warning when pasting into tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124275/feature-request-large-warning-when-pasting-into-tag-wikis), and many more.