# Are these duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

1. [Add tag wiki/excerpt audits with copied content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238339/350567)
2. [We need tag wiki plagiarism audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201799/350567)

I'm very curious why they aren't duplicates. Both are requesting basically the same feature, with highly similar purposes, highly similar details provided, but they **aren't** dupes, indicated by the declination of [one of my flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201799/we-need-tag-wiki-plagiarism-audits#comment990271_201799).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing as a duplicate is simply happening the other way round, as it should since a question with an upvoted answer is better as a dup target than one with only downvoted answers.

[Add tag wiki/excerpt audits with copied content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238339/add-tag-wiki-excerpt-audits-with-copied-content) is now closed as a duplicate of [We need tag wiki plagiarism audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201799/350567)

Any close votes cast in the opposite direction would be invalidated once the close completes anyway to avoid questions being closed as duplicates of each other, that did used to happen sometimes before that rule was implemented.

Comment: Guys. I flagged the wrong way.

Comment: New terminology: Reverse flagging :)