# Can we get a "generic definition" rejection reason for suggested tag wiki edits?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, rejection-reasons

This is related to [the other question I just asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117015/141911) about improving the on-page guidelines for tag wiki edits. Since I know, in the back of my mind, that there will always be people who don't *read* the instructions even *if* the guidelines are relevant and helpful, I'd like to avoid having to always copy and paste the link to [that one blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) when rejecting useless tag wiki edits.

*Copied content* doesn't always apply since sometimes people paraphrase, and neither *too minor* nor *invalid edit* really seem to fit the spirit (the content wasn't necessarily *poor*, just *irrelevant*).

Something like the following (only for tag wikis, obviously):

> **Too general**: This edit presents a generic definition of the tag topic instead of explaining its intended use. For more information, see our [guidelines for writing tag wikis](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

Or maybe even something that would cover *all* of the guidelines, such as:

> **Not helpful**: This edit does not follow any of our [tag wiki guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) and is unlikely to help instruct future visitors in the appropriate use of the tag.

Basically any rejection reason that clearly communicates the concept of *that's a good definition, but we don't want definitions* and links back to that blog post would be nice.

Comment: What about the majority of tags that don't have a site-specific nuance and do get by fine on a generic description?

Comment: @random but is the point of a tag wiki to carry a paraphrased Wikipedia summary of the topic? Surely not.

Comment: It's really those meta tags or ambiguous tags that you would see site-specific tag wikis really needed for the most part. Plus, people don't have to always use Wikipedia to draw their excerpt definitions from, if they weren't lazy @the

Comment: @random: That's really not the case at all. There are many, *many* terms that have domain-specific meanings. On Stack Overflow, PHP means the programming language PHP; on a stats site it might mean the Pigeon-Hole Principle. "Python" is going to mean something completely different on SO than it might mean on an Animals or Pets site. It's just wrong to say that only meta/ambiguous tags require definitions. Take C#/.NET, for example; most users on Stack Overflow *still* don't understand that [.net] is for framework questions while [c#] is for language questions. *That's* what the tag wiki's for.

Comment: Anyway, this is hardly the time or place to be debating the guidelines themselves, which have been around for ages. If tags are meant for categorizing content on the site - as opposed to being generic keywords - then clearly the tag "wiki" should be geared toward helping users categorize content on the site - as opposed to defining generic keywords.

Comment: I rejected a tag wiki edit on _Drupal Answers_, and I had to enter a custom reason; if it were possible, I would have chosen the reject reason proposed here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Done,

We now support an arbitrary list of rejection reasons that are only displayed for a particular post type id.

So, it is trivial to separate answer and question rejection reasons, etc.

[image: done]