# So how do you approve or reject any of those edits, then?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Don't show suggested edits that I can't approve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77774/dont-show-suggested-edits-that-i-cant-approve)

I am presented with this screen. Where are the Approve/Reject buttons then?

P.S. I tried disabling AdBlock and that made no difference.

[image: no approve or reject buttons?]

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that these are tag wiki edits and you don't have sufficient rep in the tag or overall to approve or deny the suggestions.

See [Don't show suggested edits that I can't approve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77774/dont-show-suggested-edits-that-i-cant-approve)